# Superfish Menus width plus center align causes overflow off the right side of the page

Tags: css, drupal, menu, superfish

I've been working with a client to set up a new website for their dental company. The link to the development site is here: http://virtualiellc.com/skd/

I recently noticed that the bottom of the page has a horizontal scroll bar when there shouldn't be one. You can see it on the site right now if you load it up. Doing some digging in the inspector, I figured out that the Superfish menu in that red bar at the top actually takes up a different space than it displays, a side effect of center-aligning as per the guidance of answer 8 here: https://www.drupal.org/node/308523

It's a minor issue, but still one I'd like to resolve. Is there something I can do to the CSS to get rid of that extra hang-off without breaking the menus?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the size of `#superfish-3` elements creates the overflow issue. Try removing absolute positioning definitions from both `ul` and `li` to make it left aligned and add some left margin to make it look centered.

Just add these definitions to existing rules

```
#superfish-3 {left:0; margin-left: 5em;} // skd.css line 173
#superfish-3 > li {left: 0;} // skd.css line 179
```

Comment: Uh, it doesn't have any absolute positioning definitions? The .sf-menu and .sf-menu li both are using relative. The menu causing the issue is the #superfish-3 menu.

Comment: @Alex Jensen You have position:relative; left:50%; Remove "left:50%;" and notice that scrollbar will disappear

Comment: @Alex Jensen I believe this is in skd.css file, line 141.

Comment: That forces the menu to no longer be center aligned. The menu has to be center aligned.

Comment: @Alex Jensen Correct, because you are not pushing menus any more so they stay to the left. To resolve alignment, feel free to create another question or look for a way to center floated elements.

Comment: That's really not much help, you've basically told me the way to solve my problem is to go and post another question, without providing any actual working solution to the problem I posted. Removing the center alignment doesn't fix the issue, it just creates a different issue.

Comment: I added more details about your issue and provided detailed solution. Good luck!